# Should posts containing personal information be deleted?

Tags: discussion

A user edited out an email address inside a post. I flagged the post so that a moderator could remove the revision with the email address, and my flag weight went down. ;(

So I was wondering, what's the policy on something like this? Are posts like this not supposed let alone, or is some moderator action appropriate for them?

Comment: For context, the revision list in question can be found [here](http://superuser.com/posts/267254/revisions).

Comment: I believe the team can delete them, but obviously they'd rather not have to do that very often

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators do not have the power to erase or modify revisions.

If someone places personal information on they site, they have done so willingly, and while the data is often edited out of the post as it's generally noise, it cannot be removed from the system without intervention from the developer team (and thus must be a rare occurrence).

As far as I know, *permanently* removing this type of data from the system is only performed at the direct request of the person who posted it up, and only if there's good reason to do so.

Comment: Ah, ok, interesting; thanks!

Comment: Indeed, [it's a one-click](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision) for developers, but still takes up their time of course, @Mehrdad.